# Search engine: design of query syntax for relative date condition

Tags: syntax, full-text-search, search-engine

I'm designing query syntax for a search engine that accepts relative date as an additional condition something like **since 2 days ago** or **since 4 days ago until 2 days ago**. My search engine accepts them as a plain string something like `since:4_days_ago until:2_days_ago` that will be entered inside a simple textbox.

But I'm not sure if these syntaxes are grammatically correct and if it's easy to use for my customers. So here's my questions:

1. Are there any existing services that have similar syntaxes for specifying relative date? It will be a great reference to me.
2. Any idea to improve the syntax/grammar or good reference to design that?

Any other advice or opinion would be also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmers.SE has similar question (cannot mark this one as a duplicate): https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78795/best-representation-for-relative-dates-durations

I'm quoting it here:

> Not a standard, but a convention used by FogBugz and Jira (both
>   bugtrackers) is to enter durations in simple terms like 2d for 2 days,
>   3w for 3 weeks, 1m for 1 month, etc.
>
> The convention could be extended for dates and periods relative to
>   some other date (usually the current date I presume).
>
> - today + 2 days: +2d
> - today a year back: -1y
> - next Sunday: +1Sun (use the day-of-week names which should of course be locale specific)
> - the 15 of next month: +m15, or +1m15
> - 20th of the previous: -1m20
> - last of next month: +1mL (L signifies last day of the month/week/quarter/semester/year, used a capital L to distinguish it
>     from the number 1 in many fonts)
>
> To specifiy periods instead of just dates, you could double up the
>   letters:
>
> - all of last month: -1mm
> - all of next week: +1ww
> - all of last year: -1yy
>
> To specify a period between two specific relative dates:
>
> - 15 of next month to 20th of month after that: +m15..+2m20
> - all of last month could then also be specified as: -1m1..-1mL
>
> Parsing could become an interesting business...

Comment: Nice example, I'm not sure if this syntax is really easy to use for ordinary people though.

Comment: @KoheiNozaki I think at least the first part of it is pretty easy to learn. Intervals are another story. But they also look not complicated.